# Is there anything wrong with defining static varaible the following way in Python?

Tags: python

If you have a value that doesn't change, is there anything wrong with defining it just with @property and return the value as follows:

```
class Circle:
   def __init__(self, radius):
      self.radius = radius

   @property
   def pi(self):
       return  3.14

   def area(self):
        return self.pi * self.radius
```

Since PI shouldn't change and the value is static, is there anything wrong defining it with @property as shown above?

What I usually see is the following:

```
class Circle:
   def __init__(self, radius):
      self.radius = radius
      self.pi = 3.14

   def area(self):
        return self.pi * self.radius
```

Comment: Um... area != self.pi * self.radius...  area=self.pi * diameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python programmers I know generally avoid accessor functions, unless they're actually performing computation. In this case you'd be better off with making the variable a member of the class:

```py
class Circle:
    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    # ...
```

Comment: Indeed... the only advantage of marking it as a property is that unless a setter is defined, it's very difficult to alter it. In regards to do accessor functions that do computations - that's not *always* the case... if it's an expensive computation, then it should generally be a function to indicate that.

Comment: I think the intent was to make it immutable ("static"), since you can't reassign to an `@property` method. This would ensure that `mycircle.pi` always returns `3.14`. It's possible to make an `@property` at the class level, but it's kind of hairy. It's probably easiest to just make it an ordinary class variable and trust the user not to alter it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 well you *can* re-assign to a @property - but that's going out of your way to do so and so be it on your own head... If one was really insecure about it, or worried about accidental assignment, then using `_pi` might be a way to go

Comment: The intent is to make it immutable.

Comment: @Samuel okay - you do realise - if someone tries hard enough - no attribute is actually immutable in Python? So maybe your best bet is to just use the name mangling convention to indicate "you really shouldn't change this, but if you do it.... it's your problem - not mine"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using a property is this:

```
>>> d = Circle()
>>> d.pi
3.14
>>> d.pi = 3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    d.pi = 3
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> Circle.pi = 3
>>> d.pi
3
```

You may be able to get around this with a metaclass:

```
class NoSet(type):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'pi':
            raise Exception("Can't assign")
        else:
            super(NoSet, self).__setattr__(name, value)

class Circle(object):
    __metaclass__ = NoSet

    @property
    def pi(self):
        return 3.14

>>> d = Circle()
>>> d.pi
3.14
>>> d.pi = 3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    d.pi = 3
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> Circle.pi = 3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    Circle.pi = 3
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 4, in __setattr__
    raise Exception("Can't assign")
Exception: Can't assign
```

For usage in Python 3 change the class definition to `class Circle(object, metaclass=NoSet):`.

Disclaimer: I just tried this a moment ago and it seemed to work.  I can't make any promises as I have not had much experience with metaclasses.  I personally wouldn't do this, if only because there might be a legitimate reason for someone to change the value - if they needed more precision, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure to make it immutable, you can define the attribute refuse to be set.

```
class Circle:
   _pi = 3.14

   def __init__(self, radius):
      self.radius = radius

   @property
   def pi(self):
       return _pi

   @pi.setter
   def pi(self, value):
        pass

   ...
```

The pi is immutable.

```
   c = Circle(1)
   c.pi = 5 # The intent is to make it change
   print c.pi # Output: 3.14, it still keeps origin.
```